# Parsing Groovy code with shell.parse causes lots of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, groovy

I have a [GroovyShell](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) instance parsing code inside my Tomcat/Java application. The parsing is very slow, about 1 second for 100 lines. When profiling the application I noticed the parsing throws lots of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exceptions. I guess something's swallowing them since I don't see them anywhere in the log. Since the script uses a lot of the main application's classes I'm assuming that that's what's slowing down the application.

Is there a way for me to catch those exceptions and get their data? What could be causing them? Is it possible that I'm using the wrong class loader?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for me to catch those exceptions and get their data?

It is difficult to answer that without more information that indicates what is causing them.  It may be that you are referencing classes that are not available in the appropriate class loader.  It might be that the exceptions are expected.  More info would be needed to answer that.

> What could be causing them?

Code referencing classes that aren't available to be loaded is one thing that can cause them.

> Is it possible that I'm using the wrong class loader?

It is.  Without seeing your code and knowing more about the which classes cannot be found, it is difficult to say for sure that is the issue though.

Comment: On second thought I'm not sure this is the right direction. I looked at the class loader for the groovy shell and one of the classes in the script and they're identical, so unless there's something going on under the hood in GroovyShell that can't be it. Any ideas on how to get the message for the ClassNotFoundException exceptions? Or ways to investigate why the parsing is so slow?

Comment: "Any ideas on how to get the message for the ClassNotFoundException exceptions? " - Put a breakpoint in the exception constructor and connect to the process with a debugger.  "Or ways to investigate why the parsing is so slow?" - You could use YourKit to find out where time is being spent.